# Puppet - exclude file from management for managed directory

Tags: linux, puppet

I have a couple Splunk servers in house which I manage part of the configuration through puppet. These are residing on CentOS 6 boxes.

My definition is set up as

```
file{ "/opt/splunk/etc/apps":
  recurse => true,
  purge => true,
  force => true,
  source => "puppet:///modules/splunk/$hostname/apps",
  ensure =>  present,
  mode => 755,
  owner =>  splunk,
  group => splunk,
  notify => Service["splunk"]
}
```

This works well, but I'd like to exclude the saved searches file at /opt/splunk/etc/apps/myapp/local/savedsearches.conf from being overwritten and / or automatically update the copy contained within Puppet with the version kept on the local server.

Is there a ready way to do this? I looked over the documentation and didn't see anything.

Comment: Fixed what I believe was a typo. Correct?

Comment: I figured it had to be a typo, but just wanted to make sure I didn't do something stupid. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add `ignore    => "savedsearches.conf"` to the file stanza to exclude it from operations on the managed directory.

```
file{ "/opt/splunk/etc/apps":
  recurse => true,
  purge => true,
  force => true,
  source => "puppet:///modules/splunk/$hostname/apps",
  ensure =>  present,
  mode => 755,
  owner =>  splunk,
  group => splunk,
  ignore => "savedsearches.conf"
  notify => Service["splunk"]
}
```

Comment: Documented at http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#file